# Creating a duplicate UPDATE with a different value based on a WHERE clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a couple of tables that relate to movies in MySQL 5.7. Here is the schema I was given to use:

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `director` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `genres` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `genres_in_movies` (
  `genre_id` int NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`genre_id`) REFERENCES `genres`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `movies`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I can not change this schema. Some of the genre data I was given was abbreviated. So I have some genres like `Romance`, `Comedy`.. etc, and some genres like `Rom`,`Com`, and what brings me to ask my question: `RnC` which stands for **two** different genres: `Romance`, and `Comedy`.

So far, I've been doing the following to update my tables:

```
UPDATE genres SET genres.name = 'Romance' WHERE genres.name = 'Rom';
UPDATE genres SET genres.name = 'Comedy' WHERE genres.name = 'Com';
```

But I'm having trouble understanding how to break up one entry in my table into two separate entries for the genre `RnC`.

So currently, my genres table has an entry like this:

```
genres (old)
==================
id  |  name      |
==================
2   | RnC        |
------------------
6   | RnC        |
------------------
45  | RnC        |
==================
```

But I need to split these up into this (assuming `90` is the next available `genres.id`):

```
genres (new)
==================
id  |  name      |
==================
2   | Romance    |
------------------
6   | Romance    |
------------------
45  | Romance    |
------------------
90  | Comedy     |
------------------
91  | Comedy     |
------------------
92  | Comedy     |
==================
```

I also need my `genres_in_movies` table to update. Originally, my `genres_in_movies` table (still tied to the `RnC` genre) looked like this:

```
genres_in_movies (old)
=====================
genre_id | movie_id |
=====================
2        | 10       |
---------------------
6        | 42       |
---------------------
45       | 92       |
=====================
```

With the way I split up my `genres` table, I would need `genres_in_movies` to update to this:

```
genres_in_movies (new)
=====================
genre_id | movie_id |
=====================
2        | 10       |
---------------------
6        | 42       |
---------------------
45       | 92       |
---------------------
90       | 10       |
---------------------
91       | 42       |
---------------------
92       | 92       |
=====================
```

Is there some combination of `UPDATE` and `SELECT` I can use to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the split values execute 2 statements. INSERT FROM SELECT and the UPDATE

```
INSERT INTO genres (name)
SELECT 'Comedy' 
FROM genres 
WHERE genres.name = 'RnC';

UPDATE genres SET genres.name = 'Romance' WHERE genres.name = 'RnC';
```